# How can I retain numbers for sorting them later?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vi

I have a problem that sounds like this: Write a shell script that for each file from the command line will output the
number of words that are longer than the number k read from keyboard.
The output must be ordered by the number of words.

How can i retain the number of characters of each file,for sorting them?

I tried something like that :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ #@ -ne 1 ]
        then exit 1
fi
array[$@]=''
echo -n "Give the number>"
read k
for f in $@;
do
        n=`$f | wc -c`
        if [ $n -gt $k ];
        then
                i++
                array[i]=$n
        fi
done
echo {array[@]} | sort -n
```

Comment: Reading `k` from stdin is a horrible interface.  Imagine if `grep` worked that way! Make `k` the first argument.

Comment: It is essentially never correct to use `$@`; you should always use `"$@"`.  That preserves the spaces in the file names.  You should also use `$(…)` in preference to back-ticks.  You don't need the semicolon at the end of the `for` or `if` statements if the `do` or `then` is not on the same line.

Comment: Please can you clarify whether you want the list of files where the number of words (of any length) is larger than the threshold `k` (along with the number of words in the file), or whether you want the list of files with the number of words in each file where the length of the word is longer than the threshold `k`.  Of the 3 current answers, 2 solve the first problem and 1 solves the second.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is:

- Write a shell script that for each file from the command line will output the number of words that are longer than the number `k` read from keyboard. The output must be ordered by the number of words.

I decline to answer prompts — commands take arguments. I'll go with William Pursell's suggestion that the number is the first argument — it is a reasonable solution.  An alternative uses an option like `-l 23` for the length (and other options to tweak other actions).

The solutions I see so far are counting the number of words, but not the number of words longer than the given length.  This is a problem.  For that, I think `awk` is appropriate:

```
awk -v min=$k '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if (length($i) >= min) print $i; }'
```

This generates the words at least `min` characters one per line on the standard output.  We'll do this one file at a time, at least in the first pass.

We can then count the number of such words with `wc -l`.  Finally, we can sort the data numerically.

Putting it all together yields:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$#" in
0|1) echo "Usage: $0 length file ..." >&2; exit 1;;
esac

k=${1:?"Cannot provide an empty length"}
shift

for file in "$@"
do
    echo "$(awk -v min=$k '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                                 if (length($i) >= min) print $i
                           }' "$file" |
            wc -l) $file"
done | sort -n
```

This lists the files with the most long words last; that's convenient because the most interesting files are at the end of the list.  If you want the high numbers first, add `-r` to the `sort`.

Of course, if we're using `awk`, we can improve things.  It can count the number of long words in each file, and print the file name and the number, so there'd be just a single invocation of `awk` for all the files.  It takes a little bit more programming, though:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$#" in
0|1) echo "Usage: $0 length file ..." >&2; exit 1;;
esac

k=${1:?"Cannot provide an empty length"}
shift

awk -v min=$k '
    FILENAME != oldfile { if (oldfile != "") { print longwords, oldfile }
                          oldfile = FILENAME; longwords = 0
                        }
    { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if (length($i) >= min) longwords++ }
    END { if (oldfile != "") { print longwords, oldfile } }
    ' "$@" |
sort -n
```

If you have GNU `awk`, there are even ways to sort the results built into `awk`.

Comment: Good to know **reading comprehension** is not a lost art in modern society `:p`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I don't know whether dinosaurs like me are representative of modern society :D — :(

Comment: It does seem to be something those who started programming after the late '70s or early '80s are challenged with. Perhaps this is part of the **age:wisdom** dichotomy?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: sometimes, the difficulty is English as a Second Language; English isn't the easiest language in the world to understand for people for whom it is not their mother tongue.

Comment: I think it's an assignment and for this reason, this answer responds to the actual problem. But the title, the first paragraph, the second paragraph, the code tell a different story and it's easy to get confused. In any case my vote up.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the script a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
(( $# > 0 )) || exit
read -r -p 'Enter number > ' k
wc -w "$@" | sed '$d' | gawk -v k="$k" '$1>k{print $0}' | sort -nr
```

where

- `read -r -p ...` prompts and read the input
- `wc -w` - counts the words of all files what you entered as arguments
- `sed ...` - skips the last line `(total...)`
- `awk` skips lines where count is less than `$k`
- `sort` - for sorting the output

With the great help of @Tom Fench [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29186521/632407) it can be simplified to:

```
wc -w "$@" | awk -v k="$k" 'NR>1&&p>k{print p}{p=$1}' | sort -nr
```

or with filenames (based on @Wintermute's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29186521/632407))

```
wc -w "$@" | awk -v k="$k" 'p { print p; p="" } $1 > k { p = $0 }' | sort -nr
```

### EDIT

Based on @Jonathan Leffler's comment adding a variant for for counting words what are longer as number `k` in each file.

```
#!/bin/bash
(( $# > 0 )) || exit
read -r -p 'Enter number > ' k
let k++
grep -HoP "\b\w{${k:-3},}\b" "$@" |\
 awk -F: '{f[$1]++}END{for(n in f)print f[n],n}' |\
 sort -nr
```

Where:

- the `grep...` searches for the words what are longer as the entered number (omit the `let` line if want *equal and longer*). prints out lines like:

```
file1:word1
file1:word2
...
file2:wordx
file2:wordy
```

- and the awk count the frequency based on the 1st field, e.g. count by filename.

Comment: In my opinion, this misinterprets the question.  The question is about the number of words longer than a given length in each file, not a count of the words in each file if the total word count is bigger than the given number.  Using `wc -w` loses the relevant information immediately.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - hm, I understand it as "find files where the number of words is bigger than the entered number` - _in line_ with the "OP's"  expample code where he using `wc -c` too. Anyway, will update my answer. ;)

Comment: So I see.  The text says 'output the number of words that are longer than the number k' which, to my understanding of the English, means that you have to evaluate the length of each word in the file, and only count the words that are longer than the given length.  It will be up to the OP to decide, ultimately.