# awk - skip last line for condition

Tags: awk

When I wrote an answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29185907/632407) I used the following:

```
something | sed '$d' | awk '$1>3{print $0}'
```

e.g.

- print only lines where the 1st field is bigger than 3 (awk)
- but omit the last line `sed '$d'`.

This seems for me a bit of duplicate work, surely it is possible to do the above only with `awk` - without the `sed`?

I'm an awkdiot - so, can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {1..10} | awk 'NR>1&&p>3{print p}{p=$1}'
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Basically, print the first field of the *previous* line, rather than the current one.

---

As Wintermute has rightly pointed out in the comments (thanks), in order to print the whole line, you can modify the code to this:

```
awk 'p { print p; p="" } $1 > 3 { p = $0 }'
```

This only assigns the contents of contents of the line to `p` if the first field is greater than 3.

Comment: This works only if the line consists of a single number, though. That doesn't seem to be a problem in OP's case, but allow me anyway to leave the modified version `awk 'p { print p; p="" } $1 > 3 { p = $0 }'` that selects lines based on the value of a field. (still +1 because one-behind printing is, of course, the way to go about it)